# Use NetBeans(Xdebug) to debug Symfony or Zend project, many variable value cannot be shown, why?

Tags: java, php, symfony, zend-framework, netbeans

I am using NetBeans(Xdebug) to debug Symfony or Zend project, many variable value cannot be shown. For example, here we hava a class from Symfony framework, when Xdebug is debugging into this class, all the $moduleName, $actionName value cannot be shown(even add them into watches):

```
class sfFrontWebController extends sfWebController
{
  public function dispatch()
  {
    try
    {
            sfFilter::$filterCalled = array();
            $request    = $this->context->getRequest();
      $moduleName = $request->getParameter('module');
      $actionName = $request->getParameter('action');
      if (empty($moduleName) || empty($actionName))
      {
        throw new sfError404Exception(sprintf('Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "%s" (%s/%s).', $request->getPathInfo(), $moduleName, $actionName));
      }
            $this->forward($moduleName, $actionName);
    }
    catch (sfException $e)
    {
      $e->printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
      sfException::createFromException($e)->printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Is this because PHP xDebug is just quite crappy? It's just a crappy toy?

If using Eclipse to debug JaveEE SSH projects, can I see the value of each variable??

btw, I am using Mac, is Netbeans weaker on Mac than on Windows?

Comment: Maybe those values are just null for xdebug there is nothing. try initializing them with null, normally you should see null or the value after you get the parameters

Comment: I would suggest testing this with PHPStorm, I have not experienced this of problems in PHPStorm.

Comment: @M.M. I will try PHPStrom, but PHPStorm is still using xDebug, right? btw, I am using Mac, is Netbeans weaker on Mac than on Windows?

Comment: I've been using xDebug with PHPStorm for a while now on OSX and Windows. At least you will figure out if it's NetBeans or xDebug that's at fault.